# How to push code to webserver every time I make a commit to a branch?

Tags: git, apache, amazon-web-services, github, deployment

I have a LAMP stack (RHEL 7, apache 2.4) on AWS ec2 instance and my webroot directory is var/www/html. My php code reside in a remote private github repository (note: this is a *private* repo). I would like to make an automatic deployment such that, everytime I commit to a branch (NOT master, but another branch), the updated php file would be immediately available on webserver.

How to do this in simplest way? Pls note, I have verified we have connectivity to github from aws ec2 instance and we can install git client on ec2 instance.

Answer (score 1):

Use a client side post-commit hook to push it. See https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks. Don't forget to make the .git/hooks/post-commit file executable and remember that the hook file isn't part of the repo that gets pushed back to the server.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. After going thru the documentation, it seems I can use post-commit hook to automatically push the code to web root. However, for this I would need to set up the local repo on webserver ( say, /home/project) and any commit made to local would be immediately available under /var/www/html. My requirement is, whenever I do a commit to the "origin" from my windows machine (git commit and push), it would also do a push to webserver. So, the trigger is coming from my pc to remote and then it should also push to webserver. Thoughts?

Comment: Ok, in the post commit hook, maybe you can look at which branch the commit was made on, and if its your branch of interest, you can do the push. You can figure out which branch is the active branch by parsing the output of git branch for a branch name starting with the asterisk or you could look at the .git/HEAD file as it points to the current ref (branch). You could generalize this by naming the branch in a special way such that if that special pattern is found in the branch name, then the script would automatically know to push and where to push, if you want to get fancy.

Comment: There is also a pre-push hook that you can tap into if you want to trigger on the push to  your local repo. There also look like pre-receive and other hooks that say that they are run on the local repo when they receive commits, so perhaps you could also put logic into your local repo that then pushes itself to the remote one.